# How do I get a four foot butt?

Tags: exercise, squats, bodyweight-exercises

[This article](http://nypost.com/2016/04/01/what-2000-squats-per-day-get-you/) says these twins do 2000 squats per day. I'm up to 75. I squat straight down, then straight up, even holding a 5 lb weight behind my back. My jeans only feel tight around my thighs. What am I doing wrong?

[image: 4 foot butts]

Comment: Doing squats with your feet facing more towards parallel can work the glutes more instad of the quads. and more importantly as JJosaur points out, it's not JUST squats, it's a whole diet and exercise regime that they've been doing for years. It will take time and effort to get similar results.

Comment: This is a very strange thing to aspire to. But, to each, his own.

Comment: @rrirower To each *her* own. Why not? I'm already 3/4 there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where to begin...

**Lets assess what is right:**

- Squats are a great exercise to build muscle in the glutes (butt).
- To build muscle in a specific area, you need to use weights to build up the muscle in that area.

**What is wrong:**

- Squats alone will get you a 'four foot butt'.
- The pictured physique is healthy for you and your spine.

Taking a look at the article, there are some good points to take away:

> the sisters sustain their fit frames using the regimen he created,
>   which includes a mixture of boxing, weight training, MMA, plyometrics
>
> ...
>
> A solid exercise routine is only half the battle for these two, as they maintain their 36-22-46 measurements with an identical diet of smoothies, salads, protein shakes and fat burners as well.
>
> “We generally stick to a healthy diet and it’s the same all the time. We are very strict about this,” Miriam notes.

So in summary, these two ladies get their physique from:

- Weightlifting
- Boxing
- MMA
- Plyometrics
- (implied) Bodyweight squats
- High Protein Diet
- Fat burning supplements
- Genetics

All of the above contribute to their physique but I am confident that the key to their posterior size is down to:

- Weightlifting
- Plyometrics
- Squats
- High Protein Diet
- Genetics

**To answer your question "How do I get a four foot butt":**

1. Have good genetics
2. Eat a lean, high protein diet matched to your workout regime
3. Start weightlifting, squats, deadlifts are your key exercises here. You should be aiming to lift a significant amount of weight (up to and exceeding 1.5x your bodyweight.
4. Work with a expert to develop a fitness plan.
5. Exercise 5-6 times a week for substantial time.

**To answer your question "Why are only my legs getting bigger"**

Look at the size of their legs, they are huge. Squats work your quads a lot which explains your tight jeans.

To track your progress, get out a tape measure and take photos. You will not see the difference if you look in the mirror everyday.

Comment: Also, not to sling around accusations, but synthol injections into the buttcheeks and implants are also a thing. We might not always be looking at natural derrières when seeing pictures like that.

Comment: I didn't mention that because the only evidence related to that was a quote stating that it was all natural in the article

Comment: Thanks. I had to look up [plyometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plyometrics).